# How to root phone without losing WhatsApp account?

Tags: root-access, whatsapp-messenger

I'm planning to root my Sony Xperia P, but there's a complication. Due to issues with my telco, I currently don't have a plan - my phone is practically just a Wi-Fi device right now, and in addition I lost my phone number. I'm afraid that when I root my phone and reinstall WhatsApp, WhatsApp will not be able to verify my device, leaving me no other option than to create a new account. This is not an ideal situation because I will lose the access to my chat groups and I won't be able to use WhatsApp until I sign a new contract with a telco.

Is there a way to prevent this scenario from happening?

My phone:

```
Sony Xperia P (LT22i)
Android version 4.1.2
Build number 6.2.A.1.100
```

Comment: If you do get a new number, WhatsApp will let you switch your account over to the new number and all chat and groups will be ported over too.  Then you could root your phone after

Answer (score 2):

If you are planning on using the same phone again, you can simply uninstall whatsapp and reinstall it after you add the new number. [Whatsapp FAQ](http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/20950581) says that you will be given an option to restore all the data at the reinstall process. They specifically ask to install the app from [their website](http://www.whatsapp.com/android/) rather than downloading from Google Play. (I couldn't find any reason for this).

If you *can* use the previous number, you will not lose your account or the data. Simply login to the app again.

On a side note, it is highly advisable to backup your chat history to your SD card as explained in [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/49018/23379) before you attempt anything *(rooting, uninstall, etc.)*

Comment: I think he doesn't want to get new number.

Comment: This is just speculation, but they might prefer you to install it from their website if that APK has content/behaviour that's not allowed on apps for Google Play, such as invasive collection of private data or notification ads.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Copy WhatsApp folder from your internal memory of your device to your computer and uninstall WhatsApp.
2.) Root your device with kingo root. Restart your phone copy that WhatsApp folder to internal memory and install WhatsApp from playstore. 
3.) Verify with the phone number which is lost, your WhatsApp account will start on that phone number only (lost one)!!

**Don't forget to copy WhatsApp folder to your PC (backup) or you will not be able to access to that phone number**

Answer (score 1):

Rooting will not remove your whatsapp data so dont worry until you're flashing new ROM.

Answer (score 0):

The thing with whatsapp is, you need to have a SIM CARD inserted at all times onto your device for it to continue to work. 
In your case, if you're just going to root the phone and not install any new ROM, the following should help :
* Keep a SIM card installed on ur phone at all times 
* Root your phone.
* When you turn your phone back on, you still have whatsapp working normally like it did before. (Make sure you have a sim card installed, ANY SIM card will do, not just the one that's associated with your account)

Hope this helps.